# SQL Server stored procedure doesn't seem to work when run by SQL Server Agent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, concurrency

I have an issue where a stored procedure I built to process some data doesn't seem to work correctly when being run by the SQL Server Agent. If I manually execute the job everything works fine. I also get no errors.

The basic process is I have three source tables (A,B,C), each are for a different type of service. They are used to calculate a value, and since the calculation process is different each year, there are multiple results, so ID B43 will have result15, and result16, corresponding to the 2014/15 and 2015/16 financial years.  The final result is stored in a master table that contains the ID, Type, and both result values for each record.

To make this work, I have six stored procedures that run sequentially, first for the 14/15 calculation then for the 15/16 calculation.

The general structure of each stored procedure is to take the data, manipulate it based on some mapping tables and create a CalculationInput table, which is simply there to review the input into the calculation for audit checks. Once this is done, the actual calculation occurs with the result is stored in a temp table `#Results`. After the temp table is built, I create some indexes, and then call another stored procedure, passing in the financial year as a parameter, which takes the temp table and does a insert update on the master table. After that, the stored procedure ends, and the next one is called.

```
StoredProcA15 -> InsUpdProc
StoredProcB15 -> InsUpdProc
StoredProcC15 -> InsUpdProc
StoredProcA16 -> InsUpdProc
StoredProcB16 -> InsUpdProc
StoredProcC16 -> InsUpdProc
```

As I said before, this works perfectly fine if I right click on the job and execute it. However if I then wait a week and look at the master table, new records won't be there, despite them being in the source table, as well as the CalculationInput table. If I then run the section of code that builds the temp table, the result appears there.

So my best guess at the source of the failure is the call to the insert/update procedure. Without knowing more about SQL Server concurrency, I am wondering if parent stored procedure isn't waiting for the insert/update procedure to finish before it ends and moves onto the next stored procedure.

Is this a possibility? And if so, what is the best way to fix it?

Comment: What about [SQL Server Agent Error Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175488(v=sql.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a rights issue to me. Check the User Id that the Windows Service "SQL Server Agent" is running under. To troubleshoot change it to a windows login that has rights on your db and make sure that the password never expires.

To do that :

from control panel --> Administrative tools --> Services ---> SQL Agent --> Right click --> Properties --> Logon tab --> This Account --> your windows id / pswd --> click ok to save

try this on a job that has a schedule that requires it to run every 5 mins (so you dont have to wait for days lol ) and exec a dummy sp and observe if it executes a few times thru the scheduler.

log off from windows and it should still continue.

Hope that helps

Comment: The strange thing is though it works 90% of the time.  I would think if it was a permissions thing it would never work